# Trying to get the ALCATEL One Touch X220L 3G modem to work on linux

Tags: linux, 3g

I am trying ot get the ALCATEL One Touch X220L working on linux. I am trying to do this on my main pc (arch) and eventuallly do it on a raspberry pi. 
the information I got with the sim card is as follows:

- APN:umts.xs4all.nl
- username:xs4all
- password:1234
- pincode:0000

I tried the instructions on http://linuxtricksandtips.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-use-alcatel-one-touch-x220l-3g.html

which gave me an error after the 3rd init. and then I tried it with the following /etc/wvdial.conf:

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CPIN="0000"
Init4 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","umts.xs4all.nl"
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB4
Check Def Route = on
Phone = *99#
Username = xs4all
Password = 1234
Modem Type = Analog Modem
Stupid Mode = 1
Baud = 460800
New PPPD = yes
ISDN = 0 
AutoDNS = 1
```

which gives the following result

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CPIN="0000"
AT+CPIN="0000"
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","umts.xs4all.nl"
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","umts.xs4all.nl"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
CONNECT 7200000
--> Carrier detected.  Starting PPP immediately.
--> Starting pppd at Tue Jul 17 21:15:49 2018
--> Pid of pppd: 18424
--> Using interface ppp0
--> Disconnecting at Tue Jul 17 21:15:50 2018
--> The PPP daemon has died: A modem hung up the phone (exit code = 16)
--> man pppd explains pppd error codes in more detail.
--> Try again and look into /var/log/messages and the wvdial and pppd man pages for more information.
--> Auto Reconnect will be attempted in 5 seconds
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CPIN="0000"
AT+CPIN="0000"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CPIN="0000"
AT+CPIN="0000"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CPIN="0000"
AT+CPIN="0000"
ERROR
--> Bad init string.
```

It tries to connect but it seems to fail. when it then tries to reconnect it apparently just doesn't like the command: AT+CPIN="0000" anymore, this also seems to be the result when running sudo wvdial a second time without unplugging the stick.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally got back to trying this, and I found something online about an application called modem-manager-gui. And it turns out that if you use that, it just works.